# I get "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Button" while running my GUI app

Tags: python, typeerror, pysimplegui

I am working on a project built by PySimpleGUI in Python and I'd created config.ini file in advance for settings window so that user could interact with program more flexibly. Basically, `settings` refers to this file. There were some following errors but the first occurence is in the below mentioned line.

```
def settings_window(settings):

        layout = [[sg.Text("SETTINGS")],
                  [sg.Text("Separator"), sg.Input(settings["CSV"]["separator"], s=1, key="-SEPARATOR-"),
                   sg.Text("Decimal"), sg.Combo(settings["CSV"]["decimal"].split("|"),
                                                default_value = settings["CSV"]["decimal_default"],
                                                s=1, key="-DECIMAL-"),
                    
                    sg.Text("Sheet Name:"), sg.Input(settings["Excel"]["sheet_name"], s=20, key="-SHEET_NAME-")]

                  [sg.Button("Save Current Settings", s=20)]]
        
        window = sg.Window(title="Settings", layout = layout, modal=True)

        while True:
            event, values = window.read()
            if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                break
            if event == "Save Current Settings":
                settings["CSV"]["separator"] == values["-SEPARATOR"]
                settings["CSV"]["decimal"] == values["-DECIMAL-"]
                settings["Excel"]["sheet_name"] == values["-SHEET_NAME-"]

                sg.popup_no_titlebar("Settings saved!")
                break
        
        window.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SETTINGS_PATH = Path.cwd()
    
    settings = sg.UserSettings(
        path = SETTINGS_PATH, filename="config.ini",
        use_config_file=True,
        convert_bools_and_none=True
    )
    
    theme = settings["GUI"]["theme"]
    font_family = settings["GUI"]["font_family"]
    font_size = int(settings["GUI"]["font_size"])

    sg.theme(theme)
    sg.set_options(font=(font_family, font_size))
    main_window()
```

The first error I came across is
`File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Creating_YourOwn_Package\main.py", line 12, in settings_window [sg.Text("Separator"), sg.Input(settings["CSV"]["separator"], s=1, key="-SEPARATOR-"), TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Button`

Comment: You missed a comma after statement `sg.Input(settings["Excel"]["sheet_name"], s=20, key="-SHEET_NAME-")]`, it is something like this `a=[[1,2]  [3,4]]`, `SyntaxWarning: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple; perhaps you missed a comma?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add a "," add the end of your second list.

```py
 [[sg.Text("SETTINGS")],
                  [sg.Text("Separator"), sg.Input(settings["CSV"]["separator"], s=1, key="-SEPARATOR-"),
                   sg.Text("Decimal"), sg.Combo(settings["CSV"]["decimal"].split("|"),
                                                default_value = settings["CSV"]["decimal_default"],
                                                s=1, key="-DECIMAL-"),
                    
                    sg.Text("Sheet Name:"), sg.Input(settings["Excel"]["sheet_name"], s=20, key="-SHEET_NAME-")], # YOU FORGOT COMA HERE

                  [sg.Button("Save Current Settings", s=20)]]
```

So instead of adding a list, python thinks you are trying to access a specific index of the second list. That is why it's throw a TypeError.
Now it should be fixed

Comment: Hahaha it happens dw